# MySQL Trigger creation after update

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

I'm trying to create a trigger in MySQL in order to automatically generate an entry into a table Operations from another table Accounts.

Here my tables :

```
CREATE TABLE Accounts (
number INT CHECK (number >= 0),
balance REAL CHECK (balance >= 0),
PRIMARY KEY (number)
);

CREATE TABLE Operations (
date DATE,
number INT REFERENCES Accounts(number),
amount REAL,
PRIMARY KEY (date, number)
);
```

And below, the trigger I'm trying to make work, which generate an ERROR 1064 (42000) :

```
CREATE TRIGGER OperationTrig
AFTER UPDATE OF balance ON Accounts
REFERENCING OLD ROW AS ooo NEW ROW AS nnn
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN(nnn.balance <> ooo.balance)
INSERT INTO Operations
VALUES(CURDATE(), nnn.number, nnn.balance - ooo.balance);
```

Where am I wrong ?

Comment: place your create tables as code (not hand typed), and certainly not pictures. really

Comment: See [13.1.16 CREATE TRIGGER Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-trigger.html).

Answer (score 0):

I *think* it's that `WHEN` clause; I don't recognize it as valid MySQL syntax. Ditto for the `REFERENCING` clause. (Both are valid Oracle/PostgreSQL, however.)

Try this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER OperationTrig
  AFTER UPDATE ON Accounts
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF (NEW.balance <> OLD.balance) THEN
    INSERT INTO Operations
      VALUES(CURDATE(), NEW.number, NEW.balance - OLD.balance);
  END IF;
END;
```

Comment: It still displays me : ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OF balance ON Accounts

Comment: Try it without the `OF` clause. I don't think you can bind a MySQL trigger to a specific column.